# Section mismatch in reference from a function to another function during Linux kernel build after adding #pragma GCC optimize("O0")

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In Linux 5.4.21 source code, I put

```c
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
```

and

```c
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

around the function `static int __init gic_init_bases` in the file `/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic-v3.c`.

When I build it, I get this warning message (section mismatch). I later found it is actually the `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")` line that is causing it.

```
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      arch/arm64/kernel/irq.o
  CC      arch/arm64/kernel/setup.o
  CC      drivers/irqchip/irq-gic-v3.o
  AS      arch/arm64/kernel/head.o
  AR      arch/arm64/kernel/built-in.a
  AR      arch/arm64/built-in.a
  AR      drivers/irqchip/built-in.a
  AR      drivers/built-in.a
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  AR      init/built-in.a
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
WARNING: vmlinux.o(.text+0x227cc0): Section mismatch in reference from the function gic_smp_init() to the function .init.text:set_smp_cross_call()
The function gic_smp_init() references
the function __init set_smp_cross_call().
This is often because gic_smp_init lacks a __init 
annotation or the annotation of set_smp_cross_call is wrong.

  MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms1.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux2
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms2.o
  LD      vmlinux
  SORTEX  vmlinux
  SYSMAP  System.map
  OBJCOPY arch/arm64/boot/Image
```

Function call chain is like this: `gic_init_bases -> gic_smp_init() -> set_smp_cross_call` (currently `CONFIG_SMP=y`). The message seems to say `set_smp_cross_call` is annotated with `__init` (meaning it is placed in `.init.text`), but `gic_smp_init` is not.

Without the `#pragma` debug setting, there was not warning of this kind. I'm not sure if I can just add add `__init` to `gic_smp_init()` (or remove `_init` from `set_smp_cross_call`). What is the correct method to fix it?

If I add `__init` to `gic_smp_init`, this warning goes away, but I think this will make the function be removed after initialization (which is ok maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: `gic_smp_init()` should be annotated with `__init`.

---

*Update: this was fixed in kernel v5.8, here's the [relevant commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8a94c1ab34d53476617f83610521cfb6674db8d4).*

Looks to me like you found a bug: `gic_smp_init()` is only called by `__init gic_init_bases()`, so it has no real reason to not be annotated with `__init` too. The function [`set_smp_cross_call()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.21/source/arch/arm64/kernel/smp.c#L758) is annotated with `__init`, so callers should also be annotated with `__init`.

If you compile with optimizations (without the pragma) this inconsistency disappears because the compiler simply inlines the entire body of `gic_smp_init()` into `gic_init_bases()`: the call chain is then just `gic_init_bases -> set_smp_cross_call` and everything is fine since they are both annotated `__init`. However, when you disable optimizations (`#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")`) the compiler no longer inlines the call to `gic_smp_init()`, which stays on its own as an actual function, and the inconsistency reveals itself.

The authors of the module probably missed the `__init` annotation of `set_smp_cross_call()`, or the annotation was added later and nobody noticed it also needed to be "propagated" in that driver code.

There also seems to be an inconsistency between the annotations for `set_smp_cross_call()`: in the C files (`/arch/{arm,arm64}/kernel/smp.c`) it is annotated with `__init`, while in the header files (`/arch/{arm,arm64}/include/asm/smp.h`) it is not. The latter instances should probably be annotated too as [the doc-comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/init.h#L31) for the `__init` macro suggests:

```
 * If the function has a prototype somewhere, you can also add
 * __init between closing brace of the prototype and semicolon:
 *
 * extern int initialize_foobar_device(int, int, int) __init;
```

Comment: Ah thank you. that looks like the case. maybe you could report it (or I may if I have time for that. I checked in the latest 5.17 code __init ismissing for set_smp_cross_call too, used for openrisc only).